# Java Executor Completion Service returns a Null Future

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Here's the general flow of my program:

I setup a network listener on it's own thread

I initiate transfer on an address/port

The network listener creates a new thread to handle data reception

Which is routed to an Executor Completion Service

Upon completion, a file is saved.

-

Here are the relevant bits and pieces:

My network listener's loop:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    while (!this.shuttingDown) {
        try {
            Socket socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            ConnectionHandler connection = new ConnectionHandlerFactory().getConnection(socket);
            this.nodeController.updateEvent(connection);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I then create a Sending Connection Handler to send the file and add it to an executor completion thread pool. The code for my executor is exceedingly simple:

```
@Override
public void execute(Runnable connection) {
    (new Thread(connection)).start();

}
```

The runnable code for a Sending Connection Handler is as follows:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try {

        File f = new File(this.send);
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();

        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
          out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        this.socket.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Upon hearing a new connection, my network listener calls updateEvent(), which is:

```
public void updateEvent(ConnectionHandler connection){

    Future<FileInfo> futureFileInfo = this.execService.submit(connection);
    try {
        while(!futureFileInfo.isDone()){
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        FileInfo fileInfo = futureFileInfo.get();

        doStuff(fileInfo);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The runnable code for my Receiving Connection Handler is such:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        InputStream in = this.socket.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
          out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        out.flush();
        setFileInfo(out.toByteArray());

        out.close();
        in.close(); 
        this.socket.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the callable code:

```
@Override
public FileInfo call(){
    return this.fileInfo;
}
```

The method setFileInfo(byte[]) creates the 'this.fileInfo' object.

So, at the end of the day, my future is null and I cannot seem to figure out why. Any ideas as to the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

According to ExecutorService documentation

Future submit(Runnable task, T result);

```
/**
 * Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future
 * representing that task. The Future's <tt>get</tt> method will
 * return <tt>null</tt> upon <em>successful</em> completion.
 *
 * @param task the task to submit
 * @return a Future representing pending completion of the task
 * @throws RejectedExecutionException if the task cannot be
 *         scheduled for execution
 * @throws NullPointerException if the task is null
```

**It will return null upon successful completion.**

Comment: The executor completion service has different documentation: "Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns a Future representing the pending results of the task. Upon completion, this task may be taken or polled." Additionally, I'm using this method: public Future<V> submit(Callable<V> task)